# Path works for 2 files but not the third. Workaround?

Tags: xcode, file, load, bundle

I have three values for the `shaderFile` passed to this method call:

```
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:shaderFile ofType:fileSuffix];
```

The values are all specified in exactly the same way in the code, and each is the name of a separate file which really exists in my project directory, and within Xcode in the 'Supporting Files' group. Each file is the same type (they're shader files) and has exactly the same permissions and ownership.

The first two files load successfully - the file path is reported correctly. The third produces a 'nil' value for `filepath`. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

I've tried deleting the app from my iPad, cleaning the project, deleting those files and starting all over again. Nothing's changed.

Does anyone have any workaround suggestions? This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding files manually to be bundled:

Left click on project in navigator hierarchy (left pane in Xcode by default) -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> '+'